# How can I make a more offense oriented Paladin, like Finn from Adventure Time?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I'm a long term fan of Pendleton Ward's cartoon series [Adventure Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_Time). The show features Finn (a human 'fighter type') and Jake (a shapechanging dog) and is a show which makes many, many [references](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4spot/20110408) to D&D, be it Liches or Bags of Holding. Pendleton has hinted that they are both paladins but the way Finn fights doesn't seem to fit with the Paladin's defender role.

I'd love to play a character like Finn; Finn goes for all out attacks and is rarely seen defending but he is portrayed as a righteous, do-gooder paladin. How can I make the paladin class fit a more offensive, freewheeling style like what I've seen Finn take on in the show? How do I model the way Finn behaves in a game?

[image]

Comment: Meta question discussing this question's validity (hint: mods say no): http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1349/how-do-i-make-my-adventure-time-question-better

Comment: Question reopened with the caveat - answer the new question posed, if this gets to be about Adventure Time and Finn builds specifically it's going away and never coming back.  Fair warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Divine Power supplement book offers a new build, the Ardent Paladin, this build is damage focused and lies somewhere in-between a striker and a defender.

Answer (score 5):

I see a few possibilities.

1. Finn is a Sentinel Druid and Jake is his animal companion.
2. Jake is a Shape Shifting Druid and

   1. Finn is a Barbarian with some Paladin MC options. Or
   2. Finn is a Paladin with Slayer/Barbarian MC options

Comment: A paladin with barbarian MC options? I really like this!

Comment: Or Jake is a druid and *Finn* is his animal companion...

Answer (score 2):

Finn might be a 3.5e paladin rather than a 4e one. I've seen many fighterish paladins back in the days.
In this case, I think a 4e avenger better suits the concept.

Comment: Agreed. Or even an AD&D or 3.0 paladin. The point is, classes in 4E are more strongly tied to roles, and paladins have been tied to Leader/Defender, iirc, so their DPS potential is not really there anymore.

Comment: Blackguard minus the evilness.